# Facing android volley lib error response issue

Tags: android, node.js, android-volley

I have integrated android volley lib for node js rest service calls. If I get response success it returns status code 200 and response JSON object which is working. 
But if I get any 400(401,409, etc) and 500(500,504, etc) related error it is not showing error response coming from service instead it showing 
Volley.error(service sending `{status:false,message:"enter password"}` 
this error object but I am unable to read this message).
How to read error response coming from node js service using volley lib.

Answer (score 1):

In onErrorResponse() method write the below code:

```
NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                  if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
                  try {
                       String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
                       Log.d(TAG, "jsonError: " + jsonError);
                       JSONObject errorObject = new JSONObject(jsonError);
                       // Here you can do whatever you want with JSONError. 
                       Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mActivitySingleSellerBinding.relativeLayoutRoot, errorObject.getString("message"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                       snackbar.show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
```

This `errorObject.getString("message");` will give you the error string.

Comment: That's great!! I'm glad to help you. If you find it useful, make it as answer and up vote so that other developers can go for this solution when they face such issues. Happy Coding :)